# Why is my Google streetview suddenly displaying only photo-spheres made by Google?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I'm working on an app that focuses on displaying Google Streetview photo-spheres. I'm using v=3.exp in my app. Until yesterday, about 90% of the photo-spheres I would routinely view by going to a random LatLng and finding the nearest photo-sphere were NOT photographed by Google Inc but by individuals. Which I like very much. Now, all of a sudden, I can't view any of such panoramas, only ones photographed by Google. What gives?

Comment: What if you try with the latest stable release? `v=3.20`

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion but no luck. Still, the only photo-spheres I can access are ones photographed by Google. Not any by private individuals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is working on adding new functionality ([StreetViewSource](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#StreetViewSource)) to the API, it is possible that things are not yet working correctly.  That new functionality is not yet documented in the [Developers' Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview) (at least that I can find today) so it is hard to say how it is expected to work.

There was a [request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4831) to not return indoor panorama's when not desired that has been recently marked as "fixed".

Not sure what version of the API you are requesting, but the "experimental" release (currently v=3.21) is just that, experimental, it may break at any time.  If you don't see the same issue with the "release" version (currently v=3.20), you may want to file an [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20API%20v3%20-%20Bug) as v3.21 will eventually become the release version (according to [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3-notify/p10_LqyBi-s), August 18th...).

Comment: Thanks, geocodezip. I tried v=3.21 and also v=3.20, but, still, I can only access photo-spheres photographed by Google, not any photographed by private individuals. I expect it is related to the following article which says that Google Map Views is dead. This issue is crucial to my app, actually. Am I not going to be able to access photo-spheres made by individuals anymore? Those are the most interesting ones. There are millions of them  in places where Google has not made photo-spheres. 
http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/08/19/google-maps-views-officially-dead-migration-google-maps-begun/

Comment: geocodezip was right that the problem was temporary.